# Nginx + OCSP - is lots of "OCSP responder timed out (110: Connection timed out) while requesting certificate status" fairly normal?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, ocsp

I've just set up a new server and have noticed lots of these in my generic (not site-specific) nginx error log.

I've looked back at the old server and turns out on occasion there was plenty of them there too.

This is my current config:

```
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;
ssl_trusted_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.crt;
resolver                    8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout            10s;
```

This is what I had before:

```
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;
ssl_trusted_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.crt;
resolver                    1.1.1.1;
```

The URL was ocsp.comodoca.com.  It's now ocsp.sectigo.com.  Both certificates are wildcard ones that I've bought through namecheap.com

Are both of these companies just rubbish?  Or is there a problem in my config?  Or does this happen alllllll the time and everyone just ignores it?

Thank you!